# How to mock JPA for Post method using mockito

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, mockito

Im trying to write the Unit test for a Create(Post) method which uses the JPA as DAO Layer .Im  new to Mockito , hence insights needed .

```
1.EmployeeService .java
@Component("IEmployeeService ")
public class EmployeeService implements IInputService {
@Inject
EntityManagerFactory emf;

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public InputEntity create(InputEntity inputEntity) {
          em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        inputEntity.setLST_UPDTD_TS(new Date());
        inputEntity.setLST_UPDTD_USER_ID(new String("USER1"));
        em.persist(inputEntity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();  
    } catch (PersistenceException e)

    {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        throw new  WebApplicationException(e,Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return inputEntity;
}
```

2.InputEntity.java is the Entity class with getters and setters for corresponding columns to employee age,salary ,etc .

Now if a Post method is called ,the create method in the EmployeeService class will be invoked .I have to write a unit test using mockito , and i m getting null-pointer , below is the test i wrote .

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTest {
    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Mock
    InputEntity inputEntity;

    @Mock
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Mock
    private EntityManager em;

    @Mock
    private EntityTransaction et;

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
   public void test_create_employee_success() throws Exception {

    InputEntity expected = Mockito.mock(InputEntity .class);
    Mockito.when(em.getTransaction()).thenReturn(et);
    Mockito.when(emf.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(em);
    Mockito.doReturn(expected).when(employeeService).create(inputEntityMock);
    InputEntity actual = new InputEntity();     
    Mockito.doReturn(actual).when(employeeService).create(inputFileRoleValidationMock);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a local mock `expected`, that you are attempting to use in an assertEquals(), but that will never work because assertEquals uses `Object.equals`, and Mockito hijacks `equals` for internal uses.  A Mockito mock will never `Object.equals` anything except itself.

Answer (score 0):

We had the similar problem of NullPointerException and it was because of the entity manager. After we updated the connection properties in setUp method, we could able to call the JPA.

You can try to set the connection properties something like this.

```
    //declare emfactory 
    private static EntityManagerFactory emfactory;
    private static EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception{
           Map<Object, Object> properties = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
           properties.put("openjpa.ConnectionURL", 
                  "jdbc:db2://yourserver:port/DBName");
           properties.put("openjpa.ConnectionUserName", "username");
           properties.put("openjpa.ConnectionPassword", "userpassword");
           //set Schema

           //set Driver Name

           emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitName", 
                              properties);
           em = emfactory.createEntityManager();
           Mockito.when(emf.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(em);
     }
```

Plus you need to modify your test_create_employee_success() to make this working. You are mocking everything in this method, which you should not do. You can try something like this.

```
    @Test
    public void test_create_employee_success() throws Exception {
    {
         InputEntity inputEntity = new InputEntity();
         employeeService.create(inputEntity);
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your insights .I'm using actually spring boot with JPA , hence creating the entity manager in setup class is still giving me a problem .So i tried with @asg way of mocking DataSource as if now , in the long run i have to try testing the real source as you mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

You need following changes in the code:

1.Instead of

```
@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;
```

You can use:

```
@InjectMocks
private EmployeeService EmployeeService;
```

2. Also as you are mocking in the method - InputEntity expected = Mockito.mock(InputEntity .class); you dont need at this declaration at the class level unless it is used in some other methods.
3. Also you can get rid of the declaration -

   InputEntity actual = new InputEntity();

   You can not assert mocked object and object using new keyword for equality.

**Clean unit test will look like this** -

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager em;

    @Mock
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeService EmployeeService;

    @Mock
    private EntityTransaction et;

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        InputEntity expected = Mockito.mock(InputEntity.class);
        Mockito.when(em.getTransaction()).thenReturn(et);
        Mockito.when(emf.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(em);
        EmployeeService.create(expected);
        Mockito.verify(em, Mockito.times(1)).persist(expected);
    }

}
```

Comment: It works .Appreciate your insights ,its clean and simple ,made me to understood the concept